# преобразование столбца файла csv в список

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

Есть файл 1.csv. В нём есть столбец с заглавием "SBX-1237". Я читаю файл csv и преобразую столбец с заглавием "SBX-1237" в список SBX:

```
import pandas as pd
file = pd.read_csv('1.csv')
SBX = file['SBX-1237'].tolist()
```

Вопрос: возможно ли при преобразовании столбца в список "отбросить" часть "-1237" в заглавии чтоб получить в таком виде:

```
SBX = file['SBX'].tolist()
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это название колонки (столбца). Если колонка, начинающаяся на `SBX`, у вас точно одна и вы не знаете, как она называется целиком, можете найти эту колонку так:

```
import pandas as pd
file = pd.read_csv('1.csv')
sbx_column = [col for col in file.columns if col.startswith('SBX')][0]
SBX = file[sbx_column].tolist()
```

Comment: спасибо большое! именно это и надо было.